# Which configuration files do I need to modify to make the Cnosdb data crying time consistent with the current time

Tags: rust, time-series, cnosdb

We see that the time after logging in to the container is wrong. Copy the /etc/localtime of the server to the container. The time of the container is normal, but the time of logging in to the cnosdb database and querying the database is still wrong. What configurations do we need to modify?

```sql
select now();
```

| now() |
| --- |
| 2023-04-27T09:43:27.146063187Z |